# Recreating an index in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I ran `db.users.getIndexes()` and copied the output:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "local.email" : 1
    },
    "name" : "local.email_1",
    "ns" : "howl.users",
    "background" : true,
    "safe" : null
}
```

I added in `"sparse": true"` and tried to recreate the index (after dropping it) with this command:

```
db.users.createIndex({  "v" : 1, "unique" : true, "sparse" : true, "key" : { "local.email" : 1 },"name" : "local.email_1", "ns" : "howl.users","background" : true, "safe" : null   });
```

It failed with this message:

> "errmsg" : "exception: bad index key pattern { v: 1.0, unique: true,
>   sparse: true, key: { local.email: 1.0 }, name: \"local.email_1\", ns:
>   \"howl.users\", background: true, safe: null }: Unknown index plugin
>   'local.email_1'"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you update the datatbase? This may sound like a dumb question, just want to make sure before i post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an _id key index which mongo dont allow to create update or delete .

If you want to create and index with key sparse and value true .

You can use :

```
db.users.createIndex({"sparse" : true});
```